# unmarshal yaml to proto3 with oneOf protobuf field

Tags: go, yaml, protocol-buffers

I have a proto message with a structure like this:

```golang
syntax = "proto3";

message Bar {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  int64 value = 3;
}

message Msg {
  int32 baz = 1;
  oneof some_union {
     string foo = 2;
     Bar bar = 3;
  }
}
```

I could think of two approaches to write yaml equivalent of the message.
In the first approach, see below example, it assigns `"some_union": null` and no value is set in the field "foo".

```golang
baz: 0
foo: "some_string"
```

In the second approach, see below example, it throws an error saying `cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field`

```golang
baz: 0
some_union:
  foo: "some_string"
```

I am using `github.com/ghodss/yaml` package for unmarshlling yaml into proto message.

Comment: Your `baz` definition is of type `string` but you're marshalling an integer to it.

Comment: @colm.anseo This is only a problem because `github.com/ghodss/yaml` is used. YAML itself is perfectly content with parsing `0` as a string and using go-yaml directly would allow this. However, the wrapper first transforms the input to json where `0` is *always* an integer, which leads to the error.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have updated the question. Let `baz` be an integer. The problem is with the `foo` field which is of oneOf type and doesn't allow yaml to go struct conversion.

Comment: You haven't shared the `Foo` & `Bar` message definitions.

Comment: I have updated the question to mention the definition for `foo` and `Bar`. But I don't think that would help as much, the problem is I am not able to set the value for any fields under oneOf type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr;

You need to use `protojson.Unmarshal` to get the values from a `oneOf` field correctly.

---

I created the following proto definition

```golang
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;
  string email = 3;
  oneof avatar {
    string imageUrl = 4;
    bytes imageData = 5;
  }
}
```

Then I was able to create a YAML file like, which gets read correctly.

```yaml
---
name: Harry Potter
id: 1
email: harry@potter.com
imageUrl: https://picsum.photos/id/1005/200
```

The only problem is, if I do the following,

```golang
yamlBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata/person.yaml")
person := &pb.Person{}
yaml.Unmarshal(yamlBytes, person)
```

The value of `imageUrl` is not set, just like you mention.

You need to do this - first convert the YAML to JSON, then use `protojson.Unmarshal`

```golang
yamlBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("testdata/person.yaml")
person := &pb.Person{}
jsonBytes, _ := yaml.YAMLToJSON(yamlBytes)
protojson.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, person)
```

Then you have the proper value of `imageUrl` set.

Here is the link to the full code - https://github.com/mbtamuli/GoLearnGo/tree/master/protobufs. You can see it in action in here - https://replit.com/@mbtamuli/didactic-train